# Java - How to detect the vertical displacement of some multimonitor setups?

Tags: java, windows, dwm

In many multimonitor setups featuring monitors of varying stand heights, the vertical positions of the monitors can be adjusted in software so that their graphics align correctly. A vertical displacement is added to the Windows mouse coordinates to give this effect; shown in purple in the diagram:
[image]
I am building a program that needs to know when the user's mouse has reached the top of any of their monitors. I tried using `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y==0`, but this will not work when the monitors have been displaced in software because the top of the monitor may not always be zero.

Is there a reliable and efficient way to identify this offset across multiple displays?

Comment: Haven't tested it, but according to the docs, [`GraphicsConfiguration.getBounds()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#getBounds--) sounds like what you're looking for. You should be able to get all monitors with [`GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html), and their configurations with [`.getConfigurations()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#getConfigurations--), but I idk how to choose from that array.

Comment: @Siguza Thanks for your comment, it fully answered my question and I was able to accomplish what I was trying to do. Would you be able to write that in answer format so I can give you proper credit?

Comment: To be honest, I don't feel like changing my monitor setup in order to verify the correctness of the answer I'd write, which is why I didn't make it an answer in the first place. Feel free to create your own answer with that info though, I'm just happy to help.

Comment: @Siguza Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Siguza's comment, I was able to do what I was trying to accomplish. Simply put, you can find the [`Rectangle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) object for the monitor that the mouse is on by using this code: [`MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getDevice().getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#getBounds())

The `Rectangle` can also be found for each monitor using the monitor's numerical index within Windows. The code `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds()` will return the `Rectangle` for the main monitor (index 0), other monitors can be accessed by changing the index of the [`GraphicsDevice`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html)

The vertical displacement of the monitor is in the `.y` property of the `Rectangle` object; this value can be used to identify the topmost coordinate of the monitor.

@Siguza's Comment:

> Haven't tested it, but according to the docs, GraphicsConfiguration.getBounds() sounds like what you're looking for. You should be able to get all monitors with GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenD‌​evices(), and their configurations with .getConfigurations(), but I idk how to choose from that array.